# MySql CASE Execute Query Returns Operand should contain 1 columns

Tags: mysql, case

The following code returns Operand should contain 1 columns.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `student` WHERE `join_date` > '2017-03-21 09:00:00') > 0
THEN
(SELECT * FROM `student` >= CAST(CAST('2017-03-21 09:00:00' AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
END
```

but the following works. Why?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `student` WHERE `join_date` > '2017-03-21 00:00:00') > 0
THEN
(SELECT `foo`)
ELSE
(SELECT `bar`)
END
```

How if i want to perform checking and execute 2 different queries according to the checking result.

I want to achieve following result (works fine in sql)

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE term LIKE "term") > 4000
   EXECUTE (SELECT * FROM table1)
ELSE
   EXECUTE (SELECT * FROM table2)
```

Comment: Because the "Operand should contain 1 column", which is the case for the second query but not for the first one.

Comment: in your first query  your subselect return more then a row .. and in the second not

Answer (score 0):

If you force your subselect tor return only a row the also the first select  work

```
  SELECT 
  CASE WHEN
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `student` WHERE `join_date` > '2017-03-21 00:00:00') > 0
  THEN
  (SELECT * FROM `student` order by your_column limit 1)
  ELSE
  (SELECT * FROM `teacher` order by your_column limit 1)
  END
```

you should also add  proper order by on the column your need  (in the sample named your_column ) for obtain the valid first row

Comment: I need the query to be able to select more rows of data instead of one, any possible way to achieve in one query instead of stored procedure in MySql?

Comment: then you need  another query  ..  . could be you need   a join query   .. or an union query so you should add  a proper data sample and the expetced  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can select from both tables using UNION ALL and excluding conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM `student`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `join_date` > '2017-03-21 00:00:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `teacher`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `join_date` > '2017-03-21 00:00:00')
```

Note that the table schemas should be the same.

Comment: My objective is to check if any data updated since last update time recorded, if yes, then select data based on the last updated DATE. If there is no data updated since last update time, then no need to query any data.

Comment: @superhuman1314 This has nothing to do with your question, which is about conditionally select from one of two tables.